# Bootstrap accordion and addClass

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a bootstrap accordion for a FAQ project with about 12 questions. Code for one of the panels is below:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">What will it cost</a></h4>
</div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>It will cost a fortune.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the accordion expands and retracts fine, but for each panel i need to add a css class when clicked, and remove it when another panel is clicked or the same panel is clicked again, so i can show a closed icon when the panel is closed. To save writing the same code for each panel I need to create some code using the 'this statement ( i assume). I have the code below bit it's not working. Am I going in the right direction?

```
$( "h4" ).click(function() {
            $(this).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $(this).prev().addClass('closed')
            })
            $(this).on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            $(this).prev().removeClass('closed')
            })


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are listening for an event in an event. `$(this).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function ()` gets triggered when the collapse gets closed.

A better way would be to check for a certain Bootstrap class. The collapse which is open will have the class `in`.

```
$('h4').on('click', function(e) {
    var elem = $($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
    if(elem.hasClass('in')) {
        $(this).prev().removeClass('closed');
    }
    else {
        $(this).prev().addClass('closed');
    }
});
```

Now, this is a rather 'dirty' solution because now all `<h4>`tags will trigger this code when they get clicked. It might be a better idea just to use the available Bootstrap classes to add the preffered icon. Since the `in` class allready tells you if the panel is open or not.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bPUxA/)

To simply add/remove a class on the row you click on, you can just remove the class from all rows other than the one you clicked on using jQuery's `.not()` then toggle the class on the row you clicked on. In other words, the class gets removed from every row, other than the one you clicked on and is either added to or removed from the row you clicked on. If you used the class `accordion-toggle` on your `<a>` tag, the code would look something like this:

```
// Happens in your click event
$('.accordion-toggle').not($(this)).removeClass('panelBackground');
$(this).toggleClass('panelBackground');
```

I don't know what your `closed` class looks like so in this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bPUxA/) I just threw a yellow background on the expanded row. Of course you can change the class to whatever you need, but this example shows how to add a class to the expanded row, remove it when another row is expanded, and remove it when the row is clicked again and collapsed. In the example, I have added a `class` to your `<a>` tag, named `accordion-toggle`, and am binding it to the `.click()` event.